# "msg":"[doc=null] missing required field: id","code":400}

Tags: apache, solr

when Iam posting json object to apache solr 6 while indexing through java code Iam getting error as below:

the error message is as below:

> "{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException"],"msg":"[doc=null]
>   missing required field: id","code":400}}"

and my json object is as below:

```
"_childDocuments_" :[    
    {
      "entityname": "ReportDuplicate"
    }
  ],
"_childDocuments_" :[    
    {
      "entityname": "LinkedReport"
    }
  ],    

"_childDocuments_" :[    
    {
      "entityname": "Source"
    }
  ],
"_childDocuments_" :[
    {
      "entityname": "Literature",
"_childDocuments_" :[
        {
          "entityname": "Authors"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
"_childDocuments_" :[

    {
      "entityname": "AdditionalInformation"
    }
  ],
```

And my java code to post the json object is as below:

```
org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

                HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8983/solr/icsr/update/json?wt=json&commit=true");
                StringEntity entity  = new StringEntity("{\"add\": { \"doc\":"+value+" }}", "UTF-8");

                entity.setContentType("application/json");
                post.setEntity(entity);                
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();

                String encoding = httpEntity.getContentEncoding() == null ? "UTF-8" : httpEntity.getContentEncoding().getName();
                encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
                String responseText = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
                System.out.println("response Text is " + responseText);
```

Im using solr 6 server to index the data from java code :
As im geeting bad HTTP request while debugging and Im new to solr,
And no changes are done in managed-schema.xml file :
thansk in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr always accept date in format `2016-06-20T14:54:27.734Z` (it is an example) .
Send date only in this kind of format `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ` , where

> YYYY is the year.
> MM is the month.
> DD is the day of the month.
> hh is the hour of the day as on a 24-hour clock.
> mm is minutes.
> ss is seconds.
> Z is a literal 'Z' character indicating that this string representation of the date is in UTC

Send date in this format.

Comment: I am just able to accept only one answer.. i tried accepting both but I couldnt.

Comment: Ok , my bad :) i forgot , thats a different answer . mistake from my side

Comment: wrong date is getting indexed...while indexing input date was 1993-06-20 but in solr response the date is varying to "1993-06-19T18:30:00Z",  The variation is in date...any solution

Comment: on which system are you indexing this ? looks like a timezone issue . I tried and its working fine for me .

Comment: It was My mistake I was setting timezone to "UTC" .Instead of my locale or to default

Comment: see !! i told you !!

Comment: for those finding this later - different types of Solr (date)fields can accept different date formats - see https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/date-formatting-math.html - the standard in this case is ISO 8601 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1):

Check your `schema.xml` file . There must be a declaration like

```
<field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" required="true" stored="true"/>
```

You have may be set `required=true` , while indexing a document either provide its id also, or just make `required=false` , it will 100% work !! Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: when I set required=true Got following error in Apache solrs admin page:  schema:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: solrres:/managed-schema; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 6; The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Comment: are you sending id to index ?

Comment: when you set required=true , make sure you are sending "id" field in your json for indexing .

Comment: Thansk ...when I set required=false My problem got solved and also not set the property indexed..to "id" feild